# Recognize action which is switching pages in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have implemented layout with `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`. So there is a way to switch page using horizontal swiping or clicking on `Tab`. I have also additional `MenuDrawer`, which may switch page using:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(newPosition, true);
```

Now I want to recognize which action switched the page - user swiped, clicked `Tab` or opened `MenuDrawer`. I know `OnPageChangeListener` and `OnTabSelectedListener`, but both are called in all three cases:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int i) {
    ...

tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);

@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    ...
```

Any advices how/where recognize this action?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend **ViewPager** and override its [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`  there you need to handle two events `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` in the second case. create your own listener that will help you identify if the user has started swiping the page. 
e.g.

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        float x = ev.getX();
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mStartDragX = x;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mStartDragX < x && getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                mListener.onSwipeOutAtStart();
            } else if (mStartDragX > x && getCurrentItem() == getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
                mListener.onSwipeOutAtEnd();
            }
            break;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

checking if your custom methods gets called might help you in determining whether user has swiped the page or tapped on tabSelect

Comment: this method still doesn't provide way to recognize `Tab` clicked and menu item clicked, and how I can recognize (using your method) that page will switch? "start swiping" action isn't the same as "switched by swipping", not all swipes end with tab/page switch